# Content Transition Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, wpf-controls, transition

I have 2 viewboxes in my page and currently I am doing this:

```
ViewBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
ViewBox2.Visibility = Visibiltiy.Visible;
```

That means upon some button press, I am hiding first viewbox and showing the second one. Now, upon hiding I want a simple transition animation like viewbox1 sliding out and viewbox2 sliding in, something like this.

I have installed WPF toolkit, but can't figure this out.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the control you're using here which is named as ViewBox?

Comment: I am using Viewbox control, this like a Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I have found this solution, this is actually full page transition but it works for me, I am sharing this code here:

```
SlideTransition transition = new SlideTransition();
        transition.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideLeftFadeIn;
        PhoneApplicationPage page = (PhoneApplicationPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;
        ITransition trans = transition.GetTransition(page);
        trans.Completed += delegate
        {
            trans.Stop();
        };
        trans.Begin();
```